# Logging requests and responses on server with Jersey 2 and LoggingFeature

Tags: java, rest, logging, jersey-2.0

I have a REST server application in Jersey2 framework. I need to set up logging of all requests that are received and responses that are generated by the server application. As recommended I am using LoggingFeature since this is the proffered way since Jersey 2.23. Unfortunately I am unable to get any request data in the log when I use LoggingFeature.

This is the code I'm using (based on example http://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/jersey-2x-hello-world.html)

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends ResourceConfig {
public HelloWorldApplication() {
    // Define the package which contains the service classes.

    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldApplication.class);        
    Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("my.logger");
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
    handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    LOGGER.addHandler(handler);
    FileHandler fh;  
    try {
        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
        fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/MyLogFile.log");  
        LOGGER.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    LOGGER.info("Test log entry");

    config.register(new LoggingFeature(LOGGER, Level.ALL, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 1000));
    packages("com.javahelps.jerseydemo.services");
}
}
```

When server is started (I'm using Tomcat) the HelloWorldApplication constructor is called and the "Test log entry" is written on the console and in the log file. But when I call any of the web service methods there is no entry in the log file. The methods are processed correctly and I get the expected response on client side I just can't get any traces in the logs on the server.
I spent too much time today on this and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you creating a new ResourceConfig inside your ResourceConfig? You do realize that there is a `register` method on your HelloWorldApplication; just like you're calling `packages`

Comment: No, I didn't realize that I'm doing this wrong. Using register on HelloWorldApplication directly solves my problem. tnx